# FLOT show all stacked data points

Tags: jquery, graph, flot, stacked

Is there a way to show all the blue line(All companies) data points?
There are points in the array for jan, nov and dec for 'All Companies'.

If the current company in the image only had data for part of the year, is it possible to show the Blue Lines points for the missing months? (jan, nov, dec)

With out having to add missing '0 value' data points to the current company.
I don't want to show any line for the current company from Jan to Feb.
Or
(not preferred way)Maybe add the points and somehow remove the line through code?

[image: stacked line graph missing data]

I tried it as a bar Chart, and it shows All Companies data points.
Just not showing them in the line graph form.

[image: bar chart with data]

Comment: imgur maybe blocked for me, not seeing my uploaded image. Hopefully others can.